# Blending an animation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script at the moment, that when the player is within a certain distance from a deer the deer will run and attack my player. I have it idle and then use an if statement to change its animation to run. However i want to then blend it to hornAttack1_ when it gets to my player however i can't get this to work. Help is appreciated here is my script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

 public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
 {
 CharacterController _controller;
 Transform _player;

[SerializeField]
    float _moveSpeed = 5.0f;

[SerializeField]
    float _gravity = 2.0f;

    float _yvelocity = 0.0f;
// max distance enemy can be before he moves towards you    
public int maxDistance;


 void Start()
{
        GameObject playerGameObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
 _player = playerGameObject.transform;

 _controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

 maxDistance = 15;



 }

 void Update()
 {
        Vector3 direction = _player.position - transform.position;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);


        Vector3 velocity = direction * _moveSpeed;

        if (!_controller.isGrounded)
        {
            _yvelocity -= _gravity;
        }

        velocity.y = _yvelocity;

        direction.y =0;

        if (Vector3.Distance(_player.position, transform.position) > maxDistance) {
            animation.CrossFade("idle1_");
            }
     if (Vector3.Distance(_player.position, transform.position) < maxDistance) {

        _controller.Move(velocity*Time.deltaTime);
        animation.Blend("run_");
        animation.Blend ("hornAttack1_");

        }

    }


    }
```

I have tried this

```
if (Vector3.Distance(_player.position, transform.position) > maxDistance) {
            animation.CrossFade("idle1_");
            }
     if (Vector3.Distance(_player.position, transform.position) < maxDistance) {

        _controller.Move(velocity*Time.deltaTime);
        animation.CrossFade("run_");


        }

    if (Vector3.Distance(_player.position, transform.position) < maxDistance && (Vector3.Distance(_player.position, transform.position) < attackDistance)) {
        animation.Blend("hornAttack1_");
    }
    }

    }
```

The animation doesnt change and it goes all laggy

Comment: what did you try, and what is not working?

Comment: I tried adding another variable called attackDistance and did another if loop and put play the horn attack but it just kept running

Comment: I have added the code i've tried above

Comment: try to use float instead of int on maxDistance, as all other data-types are float as well, rounding errors can lead to a laggy animation.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use animation.Blend?? You can still use Crossfade and it will work. Try animation.Crossfade( "hornAttack1_", 0.5f ); . That should blend in the new animation over 0.5f seconds.

Comment: I'll will try that now!

Comment: Thanks Boomer that worked, however animations still laggy, but thanks might just be my pc!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Animator Controller` for controlling your state with `Parameters` set to your states such as `Idle`, `Run`, `Horn Attack`, then in your script you just need to call `anim.SetTrigger("Run");` when the player is within distance, and then call `anim.SetTrigger("Horn Attack");` when it gets to the player